# jQuery doesn't start after the page has loaded even with a classical (document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, resize

Hello guys I have a little problem that seams to me :

I've got this page : [maelmayon.fr/teddy.php](http://maelmayon.fr/teddy.php)

When you resize it everything goes well as i want it to be. But i'd like it to work too on the first glance at the page. The user should not have to resize the page to see how she's suppose to be.

Here is the **jQuery** used :

```
$(function(){
    resizefunction();
    $( window).on('resize',resizefunction);
});

function resizefunction() {
    var aside1 = $('aside').height();
    var aside2 = $('.archives').height(); 
    var content = $('article').height();
    var total = (aside1 + aside2);
    $('article').css("height", total+'px');
}
```

Hope you could help me.

Ps : An other little problem is : why the size of the article is a little bit smaller than it should be ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant get to the page but I'm guessing you have images that are messing you up try

```
$(window).load(function() { 
 // executes when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images 
resizefunction();

 });
```

Comment: Well played ! First try :)

So you seems to know a lot more than me, do you know if the process can be loaded with the page because actually; the html load first and then jQuery and the effect is really not appreciable :/.

Comment: sorry I'm not quite sure what you are asking here.

Comment: Well, this is my page structure :  Article (right) and two aside (left; on under the other) but it seems like when I load the page, the second aside go under the article and after a seconde take his normale position under the first aside.
Have you got an idea if there is a way to make this run directly ?
You can see what's going on on the website page i've put in my question :).

Comment: unfortunately I'm unable to get to your site where I am at probably blocked by some policy. anyway for layout I always use bootstrap makes layout dead simple. checkout the bootstrap getting started page.  I'll try to put up a fiddle and post it.

Comment: sorry I misread you wanted to asides on left one article on right. how about this.  http://jsfiddle.net/bdellinger/sutoggp7/1/

Comment: Thank you for your help, it was probably bootstrap who was fuking up everything, I just took the time to redo it and now it is working.